# How to model many-to-many relationships in SQL?

Tags: sql, relationship

I have a major problem with my SQL design.

I need to create a database which models the following situation:
I have a list of capitals, it looks like this: Berlin, London, Prague, you get it. The other list is a list of travellers: John, Kyle, Peter etc.

The database needs to be able to answer queries such as: List of cities a given Traveller has visited, what Travellers has visited a given City and so on.
My problem is that when I create the two tables I just freeze and am unable to figure out the connection between them that would allow me to implement the intended behaviour.

I read up on it on the internet and I was told to use intersection entities, which I can, but I just don't see how that would help me. Sorry if this is a FAQ, but I just could not get my head around the proper keywords for a search.

Comment: Pasting the keywords `sql model many to many` into a web search should give several useful hits.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it easier to create third table like travelers_cities with to foreign keys traveler and city, than you jan join that table with table you need and look for result there?

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

Follow the following schema

First Table: Capital 
Let say two columns: cid (Primary Key), Name

Second Table: Travellers 
Let say two columns: tid (Primary Key), Traveller_Name

Now there is a many to many relationship that one traveller can travel/visit one or many capitals and one capital can be visited by one or many visitors.

Many to many relationship can be acheived by creating a new table which will act as reference/mapping table. let say "capital_travellers"

So, This third table will have following columns

capital_travellers:

id (Primary key): Its optional

cid (Primary key of Capital Table will work as Foreign key)

tid (Primary key of traveller Table will work as Foreign key)

Now when you want to fetch records, you will look into this table(capital_travellers).

I hope it helps.

Comment: @JCHammer, Sure. if you find it useful then up vote my answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

In a many to many relationship it is necessary to implement a third junction table between the two entities. We could, say, name it travel. This table uses two foreign keys, one from each entity, to form one compound key.

Now you have 3 tables. One table called 'Traveller', one called called 'City' and a third junction table called 'Travel'. Lets assume the primary key for traveller is travellerId and for city it's cityId. The junction table takes these two keys to form a primary key for the entity 'Travel'. When u query the database for which cities a traveller with travelId '031' has travelled to it would make use of this junction table and return the cityId's to you.

If this doesn't help or if you need more clarification I recommend searching these terms:

- Many-to-many
- Cardinality